локальный node и nvm
Возможно тупой вопрос и всё намного легче, но в инете я ничего не нашёл, а сам допереть не могу.
Вот я только что познакомился с nvm и чуть-чуть в нём разобрался.
Узнал о команде nvm off - остановка работы nvm (грубо говоря). В таком случае, как я понимаю, появляется возможность использовать свой локальный node (я ведь для чего-то его скачивал сто лет назад, не будет же он просто так простаивать). Но, однако, после выключения nvm - node просто пропадает из окружения винды (то есть, мне нужно вручную вписывать его каждый раз?) и выдаёт ошибку, как на сам node, так и на npm:
C:\Users\ralph>node -v
"node" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

=====
И, что для меня тоже загадка: даже в самом терминале node эта команда не работает (или же она там никогда и не работала? я уже и не помню)
Такая потребность у меня появилась из-за того, что я услышал, мол все пакеты скачанные на одной версии, нужно прокидывать и в новую (которую использовать собираешься). Но в данный момент мне это не сильно интересно и я хочу использовать все свои ранее (которые я в течение своей жизни качал) установленные пакеты.
=====
ps: я уже разобрался, что нужно просто добавить пути в переменные окружения системы, поэтому вопрос можно сократить до - а как сделать этот процесс проще? если это можно


можно попробовать nvm use system 2) пакеты, установленные ранее, не нужно перезакачивать за редким исключением, когда пакеты собираются локально из бинарников под конкретную версию nodejs, но таких не много


@nörbörnën, пасиба <3, запомню, впитаю. напиши в ответ, пжлста

а nvm use system сработал так, как вы ожидали?

@nörbörnën, на эту команду мне ошибку выдаёт: Error retrieving "https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-system/SHASUMS256.txt": HTTP Status 404
